# In Django, what is the right place to plug in changes to the user instance during the login process?

Tags: django, sql-server-2005, authentication

### Background

I have a custom authentication back end for our django applications that refers to an LDAP server.

As soon as I authenticate someone, I have a wealth of information that our network infrastructure guys put in the LDAP server about the user - their last names (which can change, for instance, if they marry), their e-mails (which can also change), plus other company specific information that would be useful to transfer to the Django `auth_user` table or profile table for local reference. (*)

To take advantage of this data, as of now, in our custom authenticate method I'm looking up (if it is an existing user logging in) or creating a new (if a new user that never logged in to our Django apps) user, making any changes to it and saving it.

**This smells bad to me.** Authentication should be about saying yay or nay in granting access, not about collecting information about the user to store. I believe that should happen elsewhere!

*But I don't know where that elsewhere is...*

<strike>My current implementation also causes a problem on the very first login of a user to one of our Django apps, because:</strike>

1. New user to our apps logs in - `request.user` now has a user with no `user.id`
2. My custom authenticate method saves the user information. Now the user exists in the DB
3. `django.contrib.auth.login()` kicks in and retrieves the `request.user` (which still has no `user.id` and no idea that authenticate saved the user) and tries to save an update to last logged in date.
4. Save fails because there is already a row in the database for that username (unique constraint violation)

Yes, this only happens the very first time a user logs in; the next time around it will be an update, `request.user` will have a `user.id` and everything is fine.

Edit: I'm investigating the striked-out area above. The login code clearly only uses the `request.user` if the user is None (which, coming out of the validation of the AuthenticationForm it shouldn't be. I probably am doing something wrong in my code...

**But it still smells bad to have the authentication doing more than just, you know, authenticating...**

### Question

What is the right place to plug in changes to the user instance during the login process?

Ideally I would be able to, in my custom authenticate method, state that after login the information collected from a LDAP server should be written to the user instance and potentially the user profile instance.

(*)  I do this local caching of the ldap information because I don't want to depend on it being up and running to let users log in to my systems; if ldap is down, the last username and password in `auth_user` are accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done similar things by writing my own authentication backend and putting it in the authenticate() method. The code is public and up [here](http://github.com/thraxil/djangowind/blob/master/djangowind/auth.py). I also included a pluggable system of "mappers" to do most of the work that isn't just authenticating the user (eg, getting fullname from ldap, automatically creating groups based on "affiliations" that our auth service gives us, and mapping certain users and affiliations into staff/superuser roles automatically).

Basically, the authenticate method looks like:

```
def authenticate(self, ticket=None):
    if ticket is None:
        return None
    # "wind" is our local auth service
    (response,username,groups) = validate_wind_ticket(ticket)
    if response is True:
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            user = User(username=username, password='wind user')
            user.set_unusable_password()
            # give plugins a chance to pull up more info on the user
            for handler in self.get_profile_handlers():
                handler.process(user)
            user.save()
        # give plugins a chance to map affiliations to groups
        for handler in self.get_mappers():
            handler.map(user,groups)
        return user
    else:
        # i don't know how to actually get this error message
        # to bubble back up to the user. must dig into
        # django auth deeper. 
        pass
    return None
```

So I pretty much agree with you that authentication should be just a yes/no affair and other stuff should happen elsewhere, but I think with the way Django sets things up, the path of least resistance is to put it in with authentication. I do recommend making your own authentication code delegate that stuff to plugins though since that's within your control.

I'm only fetching the LDAP data on their very first login though (when the auth_user row gets added). Anytime they login after that, it just uses what it already has locally. That means that if their LDAP info changes, it won't automatically propagate down to my apps. That's a tradeoff I'm willing to make for simplicity.

I'm not sure why you're running into problems with the first login though; I'm taking a very similar approach and haven't run into that. Maybe because the login process on my apps always involves redirecting them to another page immediately after authentication, so the dummy request.user never gets touched?

Comment: Would you mind if I asked what version of Django are you running? You should see the same problem I do - you are doing a `user.save()` in the `authenticate` method just like me and the `django.contrib.auth.login()` call should try to save based on the `request.user` and fail because of a unique constraint violation just like me... Unless you manually populate people in auth_user using the admin interface or some other method...

Comment: See my edit to the question. Following the Django code closely reveals that they expect the user to be modified in the authenticate method. I'm trying to figure out what I am doing wrong...

Comment: I'm selecting your answer because you provide a link to a working example. It looks like modifying the user instance in `authenticate()` like we are both doing is the only way to go. My answer below has more info on why I was getting a unique constraint violation. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This will be a two part answer to my own question.

1. What is the right place to plug in changes to the user instance during the login process?

   Judging from the Django code, my current implementation, and [thraxil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/156633/thraxil)'s answer above, I can only assume that **it is expected and OK to modify the user instance in a custom authenticate() method.**

   It smells wrong to me, as I said in my question, but the django code clearly assumes that it is possible that a user instance will be modified and I can find no other hooks to apply changes to the user model AFTER authentication, elsewhere.

   So, if you need an example, look at [thraxil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/156633/thraxil)'s [code](http://github.com/thraxil/djangowind/blob/master/djangowind/auth.py) - in the selected answer to my question.
2. Why my implementation is working differently from [thraxil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/156633/thraxil)'s and generating a unique constraint violation?

   This one was rather nasty to figure out.

   **There is absolutely nothing wrong with Django.** Well, if it already supported multiple databases (it is coming, I know!!!) I probably wouldn't have the problem.

   I have multiple databases, and different applications connect to one or more different ones. I'm using SQL Server 2005 (with django_pyodbc). I wanted to share the `auth_user` table between all my applications.

   With that in mind, what I did was create the `auth` models in one of the databases, and then create SQL Server synonyms for the tables in the other databases.

   It works just fine: allowing me to, when using database B, select/insert/update/delete from `B.dbo.auth_user` as if it were a real table; although what is really happening is that I'm operating on `A.dbo.auth_user`.

   **But it does break down in one case:** to find the generated identity, django_pyodbc does a:

   `SELECT CAST(IDENT_CURRENT(%s) as bigint) % [table_name]`

   and that doesn't appear to work against synonyms. It always returns nulls. So when in my `authenticate()` method I did `user.save()`, the saving part worked fine, but the retrieval of the identity column didn't - it would keep the user instance with a id of None, which would indicate to the django code that it should be inserted, not updated.

   **The workaround:** I had two choices:

   a) Use views instead of synonyms (this is what I did)

   b) Reload the user right after a user.save() using `User.objects.get(username=username)`

Hope that might help someone else.